# Inserir espaço após cada caractere da string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estou com o código abaixo tentando inserir um espaço depois de cada caractere da string:

```
temp_string2 = 'SENSOR TELEMECANIQUE XUB-0A9 SNL 2'

for b in list(temp_string2):
    space_string2 = temp_string2.replace(b, b + ' ' )
```

O que acontece é que durante a execução o programa vai inserindo os espaços e conforme avança o loop vai apagando. No final, o resultado é esse:

```
'SENSOR TELEMECANIQUE XUB-0 A9 SNL 2'
```

O que eu preciso que aconteça é que o resultada saia no formato:

```
'S E N S O R   T E L E M E C A N I Q U E   X U B - 0   A 9   S N L   2 '
```

Comment: E quando já tem um espaço devem ficar 2 espaços?

Comment: Não adicione RESOLVIDO no titulo, se uma resposta lhe resolveu o problema você pode [marcá-la como correta clicando no ✔️](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se é para adicionar um espaço depois de cada caractere, `replace` não é a melhor opção. Ainda mais da forma que você está fazendo, pois a cada iteração você sobrescreve o valor de `space_string2` (ou seja, a cada iteração o `replace` anterior é "perdido").

Enfim, no seu caso basta concatenar o caractere **e** o espaço na string final:

```py
temp_string2 = 'SENSOR TELEMECANIQUE XUB-0A9 SNL 2'

space_string2 = ''
for b in temp_string2: # para cada caractere
    # concatena o caractere e um espaço
    space_string2 += b + ' '
```

Repare que usei `+=` em vez de `=`, pois assim o valor (caractere + espaço) é concatenado na string (em vez de sobrescrevê-la). Note também que para iterar pelos caracteres da string não precisa transformá-la em uma lista, basta fazer o `for` diretamente na própria string.

---

Também daria para usar `join`, juntamente com uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```py
temp_string2 = 'SENSOR TELEMECANIQUE XUB-0A9 SNL 2'

space_string2 = ''.join(f'{b} ' for b in temp_string2)
print(space_string2)
```

Ou ainda, juntando os caracteres da string, usando o espaço como separador:

```py
temp_string2 = 'SENSOR TELEMECANIQUE XUB-0A9 SNL 2'

# a diferença é que este não coloca o espaço no final
# por isso tenho que adicionar manualmente
space_string2 = ' '.join(temp_string2) + ' '
print(space_string2)
```

A diferença é que o primeiro adiciona um espaço depois de todos os caracteres, inclusive o último (ou seja, a string termina com um espaço). Já o segundo não coloca este espaço no final, por isso precisei adicionar manualmente.

Comment: Obrigado @hkotsubo
Problema resolvido :)

Answer (score 4):

Pela curiosidade inerente a espécie humana e como forma de complemento, apesar da [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/562860/137387) do [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) já ser bastante completa dispondo de soluções performáticas ainda é possível formular outras soluções ao problema.

Me aproveitando da pergunta não ter deixado bem claro se o resultado esperado deve ser impresso diretamente no console ou se o resultado esperado deve ser armazenado em uma variável para uso posterior irei apresentar duas soluções usando variações no uso da função embutida [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#print).

#### A função embutida print.

Segundo sua [documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#print):

***`print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`***

> Imprime objetos num stream de texto, separados por `sep` e seguidos
> por `end`. `sep`, `end`, `file` e `flush`, se presentes, devem ser
> fornecidos como argumentos de palavra-chave.
> **Todos os argumentos que não são palavras-chave são convertidos em
> strings como [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout)** e gravados no stream, separados por `sep` e
> seguidos por `end`. `sep` e `end` devem ser strings e também podem ser
> `None`, o que significa usar os valores padrão. Se nenhum objeto for
> fornecido, `print()` apenas escreverá o valor de `end`.
> **O argumento do `file` deve ser um objeto com um método `write(string)`**
> e se não estiver presente ou `None`, [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) será usado.
> Como os argumentos impressos são convertidos em strings de texto,
> `print()` não pode ser usado com objetos de arquivo de modo binário,
> para estes, use `file.write(...)` em vez de `print()`.
> Se a saída é armazenada em buffer geralmente é determinado por `file`,
> mas se o argumento da palavra-chave flush for `true`, o stream será
> despejado à força.

#### Imprimindo o resultado diretamente no console.

Caso o objetivo seja especificamente imprimir o o resultado diretamente no console e aproveitando-se do fato de que no método `print()` *todos os argumentos que não são palavras-chave são convertidos em strings* é possível com o uso do [operador `*` desempacotar um iterável](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/), ou seja explodir uma string fazendo com cada um de seus caracteres sejam passados como argumentos posicionas para função `print()` e o argumento palavras-chave `sep` seja configurado com um [caractere de espaço(U+0020)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0020)

```
temp_string = 'SENSOR TELEMECANIQUE XUB-0A9 SNL 2'

print(*temp_string, sep=" ", end=" \n")            
#S E N S O R   T E L E M E C A N I Q U E   X U B - 0 A 9   S N L   2
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/pHDEH6)</sup>

#### Armazenado o resultado em uma variável para uso posterior.

Estendendo o raciocínio anterior também é possível utilizar o método `print()` para construir uma string em memória. Para isso é possível através do argumento `file` usar uma instancia da classe [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/library/io.html#io.StringIO) que é um stream em memória para I/O de texto e derivada de [`io.TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) assim satisfazendo os requisito de implementar um método [`write(string)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) e ser stream de texto.
A classe `io.StringIO` é similar a classe `StringBuilder` encontrada em outras linguagens de programação como [C# `System.Text.StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0) e [`Java java.lang.StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), modelando uma cadeia de caracteres mutáveis cujo pode ser regatada como string usando o método [`StringIO.getvalue()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/library/io.html#io.StringIO.getvalue).

```
from io import StringIO

temp_string = 'SENSOR TELEMECANIQUE XUB-0A9 SNL 2'

str_builder = StringIO()                                  #Cria uma stream de texto para ser usada como um StringBuilder.
print(*temp_string, sep=" ", end=" ", file=str_builder)   #Usa o método print passando a instancia de StringIO como argumento.
space_string = str_builder.getvalue()                     #Salva o conteúdo do StringBuilder como uma cadeia de caracteres imutáveis para uso posterior.

print(space_string)
#S E N S O R   T E L E M E C A N I Q U E   X U B - 0 A 9   S N L   2
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/pvoXDT)</sup>